# I am fetching json data from api (javascript fetch api) ,

Tags: javascript

i have displayed the data in a table but it is loading all the json data from the api but i want to display only 10 row at a time in the table.

How can i ristrict the json API data and display only 10 at a time and add pagination (javascript)?

Comment: The answer depends on your API. Does it support pagination or some other mechanism to limit number of returned rows?

Comment: No the api does not have any limit. It only gives array of json data. @vbarbarosh

Comment: The API could offer number of rows and pagination, but you can also do this this client-side.  Datatables.net (https://datatables.net/) offers a really good and free table solution that offers restricting by number of rows and pagination out of the box.

Comment: That way you have only one option - download all data at once, then split it into pages client side.

Comment: You can use javascript plugins like datatable to get client-side pagination.